# Make user’s first and last name as user slug

Tags: slug, profiles

I allow users to sign up with their first name, last name and e-mail addresses. I want to make their first and last name as slug. For example user first name is “John” and last name is “James”. The slug should be example.com/users/john-james/ I do not want to use any plugin to make changes.

There are already 300 registered members on the website and i want to change their slug too.

Comment: Hey, you have to change their **user_login** meta to achieve that.

PS : By default the user_login is composed by the first and last name of a user !

Comment: @RachidChihabi Could you please let me know how can i do this?

Comment: i just put an answer cuz comments are limited...see bellow

Answer (score 0):

To update existing users, try to make a script file and put that code on it (you have to require necessary file **wp-load.php** if you put that file in the root of your wp instance) or by listning on a hook like **init** hook :

```
$blogusers = get_users( 'role=subscriber' ); //get users by role
// Array of WP_User objects.
foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) { //loop throught users
    update_user_meta($user->ID, 'user_login', sanitize_title($user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name)); //update user login

    //if $user->first_name / $user->last_name didn't work, try to get the first and last names by using get_user_meta($user->ID, 'first_name', true)...
}
```

if you wanna use that behaviour just after user has registred, you have to use the **user_register** hook, and then put the same code above in your function...

PS : Code not tested.

Comment: thanks! I will try this code and get back to you.